# validictory is not able to validate properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to validate the headers of a flask request and its failing. I'm trying to use the below code to simulate the same and can see that its failing to validate the headers properly even if I miss some of the mandatory headers.

**The below code is expected to fail but its passing.**

```
import validictory
from werkzeug.datastructures import EnvironHeaders
obj = EnvironHeaders(environ={})
validictory.validate(obj,{'type': 'object', 'properties': {'test':{'required': True, 'type': 'any'}}})
```

**If I convert the EnvironHeaders as dict then validation is happening properly.**

```
import validictory
from werkzeug.datastructures import EnvironHeaders
obj = EnvironHeaders(environ={})
validictory.validate(dict(obj),{'type': 'object', 'properties': {'test':{'required': True, 'type': 'any'}}})
```

This properly raises the below error during validation. Any idea on the reason for improper validation happened in the first case?

```
validictory.validator.RequiredFieldValidationError: Required field 'test' is missing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out the reason for this issue by going through the source code of [validictory](https://github.com/jamesturk/validictory/tree/master/).

It was passing the type validation since EnvironHeaders has both the attributes 'keys' and 'values'.

```
    def validate_type_object(self, val):
        return isinstance(val, Mapping) or (hasattr(val, 'keys') and hasattr(val, 'items'))
```

Property validation is happening only for dict types and the validation is passing since the code doesn't raise any error if the input type is not a dictionary.

```
    def validate_properties(self, x, fieldname, schema, path, properties=None):
        ''' Validates properties of a JSON object by processing the object's schema recursively '''
        value = x.get(fieldname)
        if value is not None:
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                if isinstance(properties, dict):

                    if self.disallow_unknown_properties or self.remove_unknown_properties:
                        self._validate_unknown_properties(properties, value, fieldname,
                                                      schema.get('patternProperties'))

                    for property in properties:
                        self.__validate(property, value, properties.get(property),
                                    path + '.' + property)
                else:
                    raise SchemaError("Properties definition of field '{0}' is not an object"
                                  .format(fieldname))
```

**Note:** Validictory has stopped support and hence not going to raise any issue in git repo. Will try using jsonschema package as suggested.